# Woocommerce : how to display a product in a category that has a sub-category?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have this structure in my Woocommerce site :

a product "P1" is a direct child of my category "C", and "S" is a sub-category of "C" with 3 products (let's say "P2", "P3" and "P4").

When I'm on the C category's page, all I see is the S sub-category. 
The product P1 which is right under C doesn't display at all.

Why is that ? How can I change that ?

Thanks for your help,

David

Comment: After further investigation, it appears that wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) is equal to 0 (which is strange) and that I don't get into the loop.

Comment: And if I comment "woocommerce_product_loop_start();" before the loop, then wc_get_loop_prop('total') is equal to 4 and I get into the loop.
This seems a little bit crazy to me.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I remove 
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' ); 
in my functions file, it works very well ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found the solution : I didn't see that I could override the display type for each category ("Products", "Sub-categories" or "Both").